# Elasticsearch: How to prevent the increase of score when search term appears multiple times in document?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

When a search term appears not only once but several times in the document I'm searching the score goes up. While this might be wanted most of the times, it is not in my case.

The query:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "editions",
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "title_author": {
              "query": "look me up",
              "operator": "and",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "must": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "editions",
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "title_author": {
              "query": "look me up",
              "operator": "and",
              "fuzziness": 0.5,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

doc_1

```
{
  "editions": [
    {
      "editionid": 1,
      "title_author": "look me up look me up",
    },
    {
      "editionid": 2,
      "title_author": "something else",
    }
  ]
}
```

and doc_2

```
{
  "editions": [
    {
      "editionid": 3,
      "title_author": "look me up",
    },
    {
      "editionid": 4,
      "title_author": "something else",
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, doc_1 would have a higher score due to the fact that the search terms are included twice. I don't want that. How do I turn this behavior off? I want the same score - no matter if the search term was found once or twice in the matching document.

Comment: it is difficult to answer without having an example of document and desired result ..however if you dont want the scores just whether a search term appears probably  query filter would do :http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added two example documents and the query. Could you elaborate more on the query filter how I should use it? Thanks, fisch

Comment: Looking at the query i don't think  query filter would be  a good fit .  i think one approach would be use the "unique"  token filter http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-unique-tokenfilter.html#analysis-unique-tokenfilter as part of the analyzer while indexing the documents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to what [@keety](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609087/keety) and [@Sid1199](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6527742/sid1199) talked about there is another way to do that: special property for fields with type "text" called [index_options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-options.html). By default it is set to "positions", but you can explicitly set it to "docs", so term frequencies will not be placed in the index and Elasticsearch will not know about repetitions while searching.

```
"title_author": {
    "type": "text",
    "index_options": "docs"
}
```

Comment: Good option, one characteristic is that a document 'term term' would rank lower than 'term' which is a downside to me. The unique token filter seems even better in my situation.

Answer (score 3):

There is a property in Elastic search known as  "similarity". There are a lot of types of similarities, but the one that is useful here is "boolean". If you set similarity to "boolean" in your mapping, it will prevent multiple boosting of your query.

```
"title_author":{"type":"text","similarity":"boolean"}
```

If you run your query on this mapping, it will boost only once regardless of the number of time the word appears. You can read up more on similarities [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/similarity.html)

This is only available in ES versions 5.4 and above

Comment: Interesting - downside here is that all matches are set to rank 1. So there is basically no ranking anymore.